# aws auto scaling, rather lost how to

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am rather lost how to implement AWS auto scaling in my usage scenarion?
I have an EC2 instance with elastic IP,  in VPC as my webserver . This elastic IP is mapped to my website address in R53. Now if I create auto scaling group with the same AMI, which I used to create my first ec2 instance, with say two instances, then two new instances are created with new IP addresses. How these new instances can  share the traffic?
If I delete the original instance, and use IP address of one of these instances in R53, how can I ensure that this perticular instance whose IP address I am using in R53, will survive after scale down?

Answer (score 1):

Look into creating an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB):

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

The DNS record for your site will point to the ELB, and the ELB will spread the traffic between all the instances. When an instance is created or destroyed in an ASG, it will automatically register or de-register from the ELB.

Comment: Correct. Also, there is no need to assign an Elastic IP to your web servers, since they are not accessed directly. The Load Balancer will access the web servers via their Internal IP Address instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So auto scaling is of no use without ELB if one is using EC2 for web server. I kind of suspected this but it was not mentioned any where in so many words, so I thought may be…i will save the cost.
Thanks again for the clarification. @JohnR is not elastic IP necessary for remotely access EC2 (RDP)?

Comment: Zeni - If you wish to ssh/RDP directly to an EC2 instance, it will need a Public IP address. Alternatively, connect to another EC2 instance via its Public IP address and from there ssh/RDP into any other instance via the private IP address (assuming they are in the same VPC). By "Public IP Address", I mean either an Elastic IP address (static) or an address assigned on instance startup by requesting a Public IP address (not static).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need their ELB to use autoscale, but you do need some sort of load balancer to perform that distribution.  It can be an instance that you create in the VPC on an EC2 instance(s).  It seems to be a little tough to identify the "must haves" and prescriptive architecture elements (or reference architectures) vs the wide range of alternative solutions.